# What is this power connector? What power supply do I need for it? (S5520UR-E24717)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, home-server

I was looking around ebay and found some old xeons, and thought I can build an home server with these, so I bought a couple and a dual lga1366 board and I was set. When it arived I inspect the board, to find some bent pins and unusual connector. The board is an Intel S5520UR(the E24717 variant I later found out). The connector looks like 5 partitioned connector blocks, 4 of them with 6 pins, and one smaller one with 12 pins. I didn't get any other hardware with this board. It doesn't help that I can find what the name of this connector is aswell.

I would like a power supply for this mobo if possible. If not my soldering skills are up for the challenge.

Image of power connector:

[image]

Comment: Most Server boards have proprietary power supplies, you would need to know the server model number the board came out of to find a correct psu.

Comment: It's an older Intel Server Chassis connector... http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/general/server-board-system_Config_Guide.pdf might help some

Comment: @Moab I do not know the model number, as I bought the parts separately. As I was expecting the normal power connectors on the motherboard, like the documentaton that I read.